# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/ghost4j/document/Document

Tags: java, pdf, плагин

делаю плагин для приложения, на ViewPart простой просмотр pdf средством конвертации в изображения. Для конвертации выбрал [ghost4j](http://www.ghost4j.org/index.html)

```
org.ghost4j.document.PDFDocument document = new org.ghost4j.document.PDFDocument();
document.load(new File(sourceFile.getAbsolutePath()));         
org.ghost4j.renderer.SimpleRenderer renderer = new org.ghost4j.renderer.SimpleRenderer();

int dpi = 200;
renderer.setResolution(dpi);
List<Image> images = renderer.render(document);
```

Ошибка

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/ghost4j/document/Document

возникает сразу, как только открываю свой ViewPart. Проблема в последней строчке, без неё `ViewPart` открывается без ошибок. Так же, если создаю тестовый проект из примеров ghost4j, то он отрабатывает с этим же кодом нормально. В библиотеки добавлено всё необходимое. В `classpath` пробовал добавлять этот джарник, не помогло. Не пойму в чём загвоздка.

Comment: Скорее всего в ghost4j одна из зависимостей, содержащая `org.ghost4j.document.Document`, помечена как опциональная (чтобы не раздувать размер джарника), из-за чего ваша система сборки не подтягивает ее автоматом. После того, как вы явно ее объявите, все должно встать на свои места.

Comment: исправил на 

`org.ghost4j.document.PDFDocument document = new org.ghost4j.document.PDFDocument();
document.load(new File(sourceFile.getAbsolutePath()));
org.ghost4j.document.Document doc = document.extract(1, document.getPageCount());
System.out.println("Total files to be converted -> "+ document.getPageCount());
org.ghost4j.renderer.SimpleRenderer renderer = new org.ghost4j.renderer.SimpleRenderer();
int dpi = 200;
renderer.setResolution(dpi);
images = renderer.render(doc);`
ViewPart запускается

Comment: но при выполнении функции ошибка в первой строке...
`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/ghost4j/document/PDFDocument`

Comment: решено. в проекте создаётся папка, например lib, в неё копируем все внешние jar файлы. В classpath (на вкладке Runtime) добавляем строки вида - lib/ghost4j-1.0.1.jar...

Comment: вы можете написать это обычным ответом и потом (спустя какое-то время, в системе предусмотрен таймаут) принять его, чтобы те, кто придет сюда из поисковых движков, смогли увидеть ваше решение

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решено. В проекте создаётся папка, например `lib`, в неё копируем все внешние jar файлы. В `classpath` (на вкладке `Runtime`) добавляем строки вида - `lib/ghost4j-1.0.1.jar`...